# How to detect the sound frequency of pyaudio input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, frequency, pyaudio

I have some basic code to listen for any input from my microphone:

```
import pyaudio

def listen():
    pya = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    fs = 44100

    stream = pya.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,channels=1,input_device_index=0,rate=fs,output=False,input=True,frames_per_buffer=1024)
    stream.start_stream()

    while 1:
        try:
            data = stream.read(1024,exception_on_overflow=False)
            # Get Data Frequency?
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    pya.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listen()
```

What code can I put in here to get the frequency of the audio input?

Answer (score 0):

`aubio` is worth checking here. Give [this](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/python/demos/demo_pyaudio.py) sample code a try.